# Looking for a Blue Ingredient

Tags: color

Blue food is notoriously hard to find, but I'm working on a dish that basically resembles a lighthouse, and I need something blue to act as the water. Mustn't be wet. The dish is sort of breakfasty (egg, bacon, mushroom & so on). Any ideas? I've heard you can make cabbage turn blue, but I don't know how. If I can't get blue I might have to go with green (in the form of some micro-herbs.)

Any suggestions for something that would fit?

Comment: Perhaps look into some edible flowers?

Comment: You may find [Are there no naturally blue foods?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3410/782) from Skeptic.SE helpful.

Comment: If you choose a blue food colored by anthocyanines (practically all the "blue" plants named until now), it will have a purplish hue, rather than a greenish one. Many anthocyanines will get bluer in a high pH environment, so you can try if that helps - just be careful not to make your dish taste soapy. I'd personally go with food coloring, just because I've never seen a blueberry-colored sea.

Comment: @Bruce: what did you do? :)

Comment: You may find [Why are so few foods blue?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/56476/16866) from Biology.SE helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blue potatoes dry enough?  Those could certainly fit with breakfast. (hash browns, home fries, etc)  Blue corn may also work in a corn pancake.

Comment: Blue Corn Chips would work too. A Mexican Breakfast sort of a thing.

Comment: Maybe blue corn bread?

Answer (score 5):

I would take 3 parts elderberry, 1 part water and heat it to boiling with a small amount of agar. Once cold you have blue to darkblue, slightly purple jelly. If you take a bit more agar it gets solid enough to be cut. It would still look like a liquid. It is not really sweet, so it would go well with your breakfast dish.

Answer (score 3):

All the blue(ish) food I can recall:

- A lot of candies
- Grapes
- The outside of passion fruit (you can replicate waves)
- Blueberries
- Elderberries
- Ice cream
- Blue potatoes
- Red cabbage (I've read that it would turn blue if you don't add apples/acid)
- Violets
- Blue yoghurt
- Eggplant (maybe)

However, I'm not sure what of these would fit with breakfast. I think the best one is the yogurt.  You can also try to make blueberry bavarois, but I'm afraid that would be a bit too purply.

You can always buy some blue food colouring and you can mix it with whatever you want.

Comment: I don't think Blue Curaçao would be appropriate, so I left that out.

Comment: When if comes to alcohol with breakfast, it must be noon SOMEWHERE.

Comment: Mien - Blue Curacao is always appropriate!

Answer (score 2):

By "mustn't be wet", do you mean anything but an actual liquid? Would [Blue Jello](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002UL5XLI) work? It's solid enough to stay in one place (unless you turn it upside down).