# Are there blue foods out there?

Tags: vegetables, fruit

Are there naturally occurring foods that are blue? Not foods that have been created in a lab to be blue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a Blue Ingredient](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15664/looking-for-a-blue-ingredient)

Comment: This is very much of a language/cultural thing. English tends to use other color words for foods which are known as "blue" elsewhere in the world. For example, "eggplant" can be called "blue tomato".

Comment: See also: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/are-there-no-naturally-blue-foods

Comment: You may find [Why are so few foods blue?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/56476/16866) from Biology.SE helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A few that came immediately to mind:

- Blueberries
- Purple potatoes (sort of blue-violet)
- Blue corn (readily found in the form of corn chips)
- Lobsters are blueish (until cooked when they turn bright red, so nobody thinks of them as blue)
- Some edible flowers

[An excellent answer can be found at Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/are-there-no-naturally-blue-foods), complete with lots of pictures.

Comment: Fair warning: The Blue/Purple potatoes turn grey when boiled. My wife still harangues me for the "brain soup" I made, unknowingly.

Comment: Yeah, I run into that problem with most blue or purple foods -- beans, potatoes, okra, all lose much of their color when cooked.

Comment: and shellfish ... blue crabs and blue lobsters turn red when cooked.  I once went to a talk where someone had some color-analzing tool, and determine that most "blue" foods were actually closer to purple/violet.  Blue crabs were the closest to "blue" (but it's the shell, which we don't eat).

Comment: None of the foods you list (except perhaps for the flowers) are blue, but purple or violet.

Comment: The flowers certainly are, but I'll grant the rest are spectrally more indigo. The OP didn't really define how strict a "blue" was needed :)

Comment: @GreyDog - Oddly enough, mine turned an intense, dark blue after stewing with a pot-roast a few hours, and a true blue, not a violet/purple.

Answer (score 1):

Even if limited to foods edible to humans, a few others do come to mind, each of which occasion in true blue hues (though not necessarily always).

1.the Concord grape

2.the juniper berry (used for making gin)

3.varieties of cabbage, squash, and mushroom (from which the band Blue Oyster Cult apparently derived its name)